# Ubuntu Update Boot Entry

Tags: boot, grub2, updates

I'm have Ubuntu 13.10 running on my Asus laptop. I often check for updates and there are times that Ubuntu downloads and installs an entry that is labeled generic. Every time this happens, a new GRUB boot entry is created. My question is, should I change the boot entry to the latest generic or should I leave it to the default 'Ubuntu' entry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When y new entry in grub appears this means that a new linux kernel is installed and you can boot this kernel. Ubuntu leaves the old kernel also in the grub configuration (and in the folder `/boot/`) that you can boot from the old kernel too, if everything went wrong.

Different kernel variants:

- **generic** kernel - this is the stock kernel that is provided by default
  in Ubuntu.
- **preempt** kernel - this kernel is based on the -generic
  kernel source tree but is built with different configurations
  (settings) to reduce latency. Also known as a soft real-time kernel.
- **rt** kernel - is based on the Ubuntu kernel source tree with Ingo
  Molnar maintained PREEMPT_RT patch applied to it. Also know as a hard
  real-time kernel.
- **lowlatency** kernel - very similar to the -preempt
  kernel and based on the -generic kernel source tree, but uses a more
  aggressive configuration to further reduce latency. Also know as a
  soft real-time kernel.
- **realtime** kernel - is based on the vanilla kernel source tree with Ingo Molnar maintained PREEMPT_RT patch applied to it. Also know as a hard real-time kernel.

The generic kernel is the default kernel of Ubuntu.

So your question:
It's up to you. I would recommend using the new generic kernel so you are always up to date. To estimate which kernel at the moment is running type this in the command line:

```
user@host:~# uname -r
3.5.0-23-generic
```